# Why like operator doesn't work - Sqlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have this query that would return a search from base with the operation Like '%srch'

```
 srch=search.getText().toString();
...
db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM MyTable WHERE Name LIKE 'srch%' or Name LIKE '%srch' ",null);
```

but it doesn't work.

Can you explain why it doesn't work, and how I can fix it ?

thanks a lot

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? What are the values that you think it should return that it doesn't (or returns when you think it shouldn't?)

Comment: You don't have a field named [name] do you? Because that is reserved in most databases.

Comment: i have textview and   TextChangedListener on it when input in textview should search any name so if  the input where 'sa' so fetch the records whatever name starts with 'sa' // `srch=search.getText().toString();` to get the input from textview

Comment: @ MLewisCodeSolutions no! i have field name in mytable in database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix the query by changing it as below:

```java
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Name LIKE ?",
            new String[] { "%" + srch + "%" });
```

Comment: The original code was trying for prefix and suffix only. Maybe that matters to the questioner.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use just one LIKE

```
 db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM MyTable WHERE Name LIKE '%'" + srch + "'%' ",null);
```

Comment: `srch` is a php variable ?

Comment: java & android with sqlite

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution i just do like this

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM MyTable WHERE name LIKE '%"+srch+"%'",null);
```

and its okay thanks all for help

Comment: This fails when somebody enters a single quote `'` in the search field. You should use parameters to prevent [SQL injections](http://bobby-tables.com/).